# Setting maximum and minimum values for x-axis as dates in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a graph that has dates on the x-axis and I'm trying to set maximum and minimum values for this axis using an Excel VBA. Below is my code which doesnt seem to work.Can anyone please help.

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue)
    .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("C33").Value
    .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("D54").Value
End With
```

Comment: Your code actually sets bounds for y-axis. You can't set bounds for x-axis because they are taken from source data.

Answer (score 2):

`xlValue` refers to the y-axis (or value axis). You're interested in adjust the x-axis values (or category axis) which require `xlCategory`. So use

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
    .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("C33").Value
    .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("D54").Value
End With
```

Comment: This will work for `xlValue` but for `xlCategory` it will produce an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I created a chart for a bivariate normal distribution. X1 follows a normal distribution with mu1 and stdev1 and likewise for X2. X1 is along the X axis. I wanted the limits to be within 4 standard deviations of the mean. mywidth and myheight were assigned beforehand. The data start on row 2 since there are titles on row 1. The data for X1 are in the 1st column. n is the number of rows of data.

```
mysheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
Set mychart = Sheets(mysheetname).ChartObjects.Add(Left:=mywidth, Top:=myheight + 2, Width:=400, Height:=250)
mychart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Cells(outputrow + 1, outputcol + 1), Cells(outputrow + n, outputcol + 1))
mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(Cells(outputrow + 1, outputcol), Cells(outputrow + n, outputcol))
mychart.Chart.HasLegend = False
mychart.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = mu2 - 4 * sigma2
mychart.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = mu2 + 4 * sigma2
mychart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = mu1 - 4 * sigma1
mychart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = mu1 + 4 * sigma1
```