# Use Max function in macro to adjust vertical axis of chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the Max function within a macro to make my charts vertical axis automatically adjust to the highest number in a range of cells. I have started a macro that isn't working but below is kind of the gist of what I'm going for. Any help is much appreciated.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D26:D100"))
```

Comment: The code you posted in the question should run without error. what is the error? when you run this line do you have a chart actually selected? do you have a sheet name Wtaerfall? is there any error value in the range D26:D100?

Comment: It kept giving me the Compile error: Expected: list separator or ) on that macro. I have changed the coding in my original question because I realized it should always be on the activesheet so I didn't specify a workbook and the chart is Chart 1 but it's still not working

Comment: Include the range: Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D26:D100"))

Comment: That worked, thanks! Can you please tell me how to make it refer to Chart 1 instead of ActiveChart? I have edited my original post with the correct coding for everything else.

Comment: Have you tried: ChartObjects(1).Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale

Comment: I get Compile error: Sub or Function not defined when I try that.

Comment: Actually it is: ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale

Comment: I get the same error with the following code     ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D26:D100"))

Comment: How about: ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale

Comment: I appreciate you sticking with me on this VBA Pete but I get the same compile error with that as well.

Comment: This appeared to working with someone with a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469890/setting-maximum-and-minimum-values-for-x-axis-as-dates-in-excel

Comment: VBA Pete, thanks for all your help. I just had to add ActiveSheet to the beginning! I have updated my original post with the correct code. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the correct coding VBA Pete helped me come up with, thanks again!

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D26:D100"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For future cases and good coding practice, try to avoid using `ActiveSheet` and use referenced objects instead.

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim ChtObj  As ChartObject

Set Sht = Worksheets("YourSheetName") '<-- set the worksheet your charts are in
Set ChtObj = Sht.ChartObjects(1) '<-- set the chart object to the specific chart object you want to modify

' now modify the chartobject properties
With ChtObj
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sht.Range("D26:D100")) '<-- when defining the range, also fully qualify it with the worksheet name
End With
```